# blackberry "Error Starting Module not found" adding external jar to eclipse plugin

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Help

I'm using BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse Version: 1.3.0

Simulator 9800

I'm trying to run a Midlet that sucessfully runs on j2me emulator(tested).

The project compiles fine, but when I run it in the BB simulator it gives me the error:

"error starting MyApp: Module J4ME not found.

I added a jar file of J4ME as an external jar file. it seems actual j4me jar is not added to the project which
is loaded on BB simulator.

Anyway, the major problem is that it cannot run in the simulator.

I found several posts with the same problem, but the solutions they gave are for JDE, not for eclipse plugin,

or

add jar to project with "add file to project" option but that option is missing in my eclipse plug-in.

or

to add jar to other new project and then add this project to main project as dependent project(this option is also missing in eclipse)

plz kindly help me out as am new in this blackberry environmnt.

thanks in advance

Comment: I also faced this same problem and had switched to JDE at last. On Eclipse did you enable the tick mark on left of your added jar on "Build Path -> Configure Build Path - Order and Export".

Comment: hi rupak 
thanks for response 
bt.. I had tried this way too , it gives error - 
 "A Project has to have a jad file file if it exports a mildlet jar." as my jar contains only class files. any othr way out ?? ?

Comment: What size is your .cod file, if it's over around 5MB you will run into 'module not found' problems.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with the ksoap2 library.