# BlackBerry App Error starting MyProject: Module "xxxxxxx" not found

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

In my BlackBerry app I have three projects; **MainProj**, **OwnersAppComm**, **JSON-ME** whose build paths are configured as follows.

### MainProj

Java Build Path

```
            - Projects  - OwnersAppComm 

            - Libraries - None

            - Order and Export - MainProj/src (exported)
                               - MainProj/res (exported)
                               - OwnersAppComm (not exported)
                               - BB JRE 4.5.0 (not exported)
```

### OwnersAppComm

Java Build Path

```
            - Projects - JSON-ME

            - Libraries - None

            - Order and Export - OwnersAppComm/src (exported)
                               - JSON-ME/src (exported)
                               - BB JRE 4.5.0 (not exported)
```

### JSON-ME

Java Build Path

```
            - Projects - None

            - Libraries - BB JRE 4.5.0

            - Order and Export - JSON-ME/src (exported)
                               - BB JRE 4.5.0 (not exported)
```

When I run this project I get this error: Error starting MainProj: Module "JSON$2dME" not found, in simulators running JREs > 4.5. 
In the 8300 simulator running JRE 4.5 I do not get this error.

I have tried making JAR out of each of the sub-projects but I get the same error.

Another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469210/blackberry-error-starting-module-not-found-adding-external-jar-to-eclipse-plug) describes a similar kind of problem with the BlackBerry plug-in for Eclipse, but with no solution.

Does anyone know how to properly include these two sub-projects so that there is no error in JREs higher than 4.5?

Thank you and regards,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I seem to recall running into something similar a while back but I can't remember specifics. Have you tried to check the export box for OwnersAppComm in MainProj?

Comment: Yes, but I still get the same error. I did get it working in a different way and I am posting it here.

Comment: Ok good. I was trying to duplicate the problem since I'm running a similar setup but to no avail. Glad you got something though!

Comment: Thanks for trying it out! I wish I knew why it works for you and not for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I got it working like this:

- I added the contents of JSON-ME to OwnersAppComm (not an ideal solution, but no other option).
- The Java Build Path of OwnersAppComm was changed to this,

### OwnersAppComm

Java Build Path

```
        - Projects - None

        - Libraries - BB JRE 4.5.0 

        - Order and Export - OwnersAppComm/src (exported)

                           - BB JRE 4.5.0 (not exported)
```

- Then I changed the Java Build Path of MainProj to this.

### MainProj

Java Build Path

```
        - Projects  - OwnersAppComm 

        - Libraries - BB JRE 4.5.0 

        - Order and Export - MainProj/src (exported)
                           - MainProj/res (exported)
                           - BB JRE 4.5.0 (not exported)
                           - OwnersAppComm (not exported)
```

And that is all! It worked and I am not sure why...